# Specify checkerboard size/amount of boxes on imshowpair in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Hi what I'm trying to do is displaying two images using the checkerboard pettern due to it's a good way of visualising.

```
figure, imshowpair(IMGONE,IMGTWO,'checkerboard');
```

Is there a way of specifying the amount of checkerboard boxes and/or the size of the boxes? In the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html) I only find "properties" for the falsecoloring not for the checkerboard.

Comment: To anybody reading this post, `'checkerboard'` method  is introduced in R2017a.